# Solr termFrequency gets reset after incremental update in nonStoredField

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr version use: 6.6.0

I have used SOLR **string** field with doc-Values as **true**, which allowed incremental updates to a non-stored field but it resets the term-frequency when a new value is added.

It allows incremental updates by supplying **add** param but it doesn't keep the term Frequency correctly.

It resets the term Frequency of non-supplied value and does not modify **tf** of the pre-existing supplied values.

For example:

I have added in term vectors to **string** field so that **tf** can be queried

```
termVectors="true"
```

Schema for my field:

```
 <field name="name" type="string" docValues="true"  multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

Consider this example:

```
id: hex
name:{a,a,a,b,b,c}
```

Now if I run

```
 COLLECTION_NAME/tvrh?q=id:hex&tv.tf=true&tv.fl=name&fl=name&rows=1&wt=json
```

I get **termfrequency** as

```
a-> 3, b-> 2, c->1
```

and now if I add

```
name:{b,c,d}
```

expected answer should look like

```
a->3, b->3, c->2, d->1
```

but my results are as

```
a->1, b->2, c->2, d->1
```

Value has been reset for **a** ( Not supplied )
No changes are done in **b,c** ( Does not match with existing data )
**d** is added as 1

This is erroneous and not suitable for my need.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that since you have only docValues and not stored, the docValues retrieval only gets a single term (i.e. not two tokens for `a, a`). Have you tried setting the field as stored to see if it changes anything? It might be an oversight in the `add` code, though..

Comment: If I make it as stored, it works but then it has duplicated values in 'name' field, which will cause lots for redundant data for my requirement, which will cause increase in size